# Unity gyroscope reads only two axes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I want to make it so that the gyroscope will only change the x and y-axes of an object. There is code for one axis and for three axes (mostly used), but I couldn't find anything about two axis and wasn't able to do it myself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the z-axis or whatever axis before applying-

```
private Vector3 startEulerAngles;
private Vector3 startGyroAttitudeToEuler;

private void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
    startGyroAttitudeToEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 deltaEulerAngles = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles - startGyroAttitudeToEuler;

    // Z-axis reset, so it won't be applied. 
    deltaEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;

    transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles - deltaEulerAngles;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man! i really appreciate your answer! I will go ahead and apply this into my code. this looks like a very good idea and looks like  it will work